# Gulp - compile and bundle js files and maintain folder structure

Tags: javascript, webpack, gulp, bundle, babeljs

I am coding many small "blocks", parts of bigger website. I need each block to have its own folder and html, scss and sometimes js files. Then all the files have to be compiled (scss, ES6) and copied to `dist` directory with *the same folder structure as in source* (every block separated). To automate the process I am using Gulp. I used gulp-flatten to maintain the folder structure and it works quite well. Here is fragment of my gulpfile:

```js
function css() {
  return src("blocks/**/*.scss")
    .pipe(flatten({ includeParents: 1 }))
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(dest("../dist/blocks"));
}

function html() {
  return src("blocks/**/*.html")
    .pipe(flatten({ includeParents: 1 }))
    .pipe(dest("../dist/blocks"));
}

function scripts() {
  return src("blocks/**/*.js")
    .pipe(flatten({ includeParents: 1 }))
    .pipe(babel())
    .pipe(dest("../dist/blocks"));
}
```

It works ok when there are no imports in js files. But in some of the blocks I will have to import some npm packages, so I will need to bundle the js code.

How can I do it? I don't want to bundle *everything*, I want to separately bundle js files for every block and save them in their dist folders as I am doing now with scss.